# Добавить class к ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код

```js
var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
var max = 3;
var max2 = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;

function selectiveCheck(event) {
    var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll(".check:checked");
    if (checkedChecks.length >= max + 1)
        return false; {
        en_dis = $("input:checkbox:checked").length < max
        $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', en_dis);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="nav-link" id="1tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="1tab" aria-selected="true">1Tab</a>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />


<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Button</button>
```

К ссылке `<a class="nav-link"` добавить `disabled`, чтобы было `<a class="nav-link disabled"`, если нажат хотя быт один checkbox.

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправил

Comment: к этому `<a class="nav-link"` добавить `disabled`, чтобы было `<a class="nav-link disabled"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На странице не должно быть больше одного элемента с одинаковыми id... Клик можно организовать по классам. Без jQuery:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');

var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".check");
var tab = document.getElementById("tab1");
var btn = document.getElementById("submit_button");
var min = 1, max = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++){
  checks[i].addEventListener('click', function (e){
    var ch = document.querySelectorAll('.check:checked');

    if( ch.length > max ) {
      demo.innerText = `Максимум ${ max }!`;
      e.preventDefault();
    } else { 
      demo.innerText = "";
    }

    tab.classList[ (ch.length >= min) ? "add" : "remove" ]("disabled");
    btn.disabled = ch.length < max;
  });
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #999;
  opacity: 0.7;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="1tab" aria-selected="true">1Tab</a>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" value="1" />

<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" disabled>Button</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: еще вопрос, как можно ограничить еще количество чеков, например 3

Comment: @Andrey Z. `event.preventDefault()` выключает дефолтное поведение элемента для этого события. Но т.к. "change" нельзя отключить, поменял его на "click". Можно было просто `if( ch.length > max ) { e.preventDefault(); }` остальное для демо.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте такой вариант, и если используете jquery, то я бы написал весь кусок на jquery, как ни крути, но селекторы на нём удобные:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.check', function() {
  var isDisabled = false
  $.each($('.check'), function(key, value) {
    if ($(value).prop("checked") && !isDisabled) {
      isDisabled = true
    }
  })
  if (isDisabled) {
    $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.nav-link').addClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.nav-link').removeClass('disabled');
  }
})
```

```css
.nav-link.disabled {
 color: #cccccc;
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" id="1tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="1tab" aria-selected="true">1Tab</a>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" price="296" id="box_1" value="1" />


<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Button</button>
```